# Determining Lebesgue-integrability of functions

Tags: lebesgue-integral

Consider the function
$$f:[0,\infty)\to\mathbb{R},\qquad x\mapsto e^{-x}.$$
In freshmen calculus, we say that it is "integrable" because the improper integral
$$\int_0^\infty e^{-x}\,dx$$
converges. This is basically saying that the Riemann integral converges. My question is: Is $f$ Lebesgue-integrable?
To use the definition of Lebesgue-integrability, I need to decide whether there is an increasing sequence of nonnegative simple functions converging to $f$ pointwise and whose integrals don't blow up, but this seems like a too open-ended problem...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is integrable. As in the integral is defined, and has a finite value. You do not need to explicitly find a sequence of simple functions to show this.

Firstly, the integrand is continuous hence measurable, and non-negative hence the integral makes sense but is possibly infinite. To prove it is finite, we can use the upper bound
$$ x\in [n,n+1)\implies e^{-x} \le e^{-n}, \text{ i.e. }e^{-x} \le \sum_{n=0}^\infty \chi_{[n,n+1)}(x)e^{-n} $$
so that from $f\le g\implies \int f\le \int g$ and the convergence of geometric series,
$$ \int_{[0,\infty)} e^{-x} dx \le \sum_{n=0}^\infty e^{-n} < \infty.$$